# Which words will be better to express these states?

Tags: java, android, queue

I have a queue and will do the enqueue/dequeue operations all the time. There are two states for the queue:

1. one is for few datas filled in the queue and
2. the other is for many datas filled in the queue.

So which words will be better to express the two states ?

I found `QUEUE_FILLED_FEW` and `QUEUE_FILLED_MANY`, but i thought it's not good.

Comment: QUEUE_IS_PARTIALLY_FULL AND QUEUE_IS_ALMOST_FULL or may be QUEUE_HAS_FEW_ELEMENTS and QUEUE_HAS_MANY_ELEEMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say create an enum called `QueueState` to increase readability first. And I would suggest `QueueState.FEW_ITEMS` and `QueueState.MANY_ITEMS`. They express what you mean and they are short so you can remember them. Isn't that concise?

```
public enum QueueState {
    FEW_ITEMS, MANY_ITEMS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:
`QUEUE_IS_PARTIALLY_FULL` and `QUEUE_IS_ALMOST_FULL`.

Or 
`QUEUE_HAS_FEW_ELEMENTS and QUEUE_HAS_MANY_ELEMENTS`.

Comment: Are there any precise english words can express the case?